# How to tell which Tab Bar Item triggers a View?

Tags: iphone

One `UIViewController` is *shared* by two `Tab Bar Item`s (i.e., clicking either tab bar item will trigger the same view controller). How can I tell which Tab Bar Item was pressed to trigger the view controller to become active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the `UITabBarController` about its `selectedIndex` might help if your tab bar contains 5 or less than 5 tabs.  You can also ask the `UITabBarController` about its `tabBar`, and ask the tab bar about its `selectedItem`.